# Android Studioでdrawableやdimensの補完、参照できなくなった

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

タイトルの通りです。
通常layout_backgroundなどをXMLで定義するとその値に補完がでますが、それが突然でなくなり、更に自力で入力するもエラーが出ます。直接値を記述すると反映されますが、これではdrawableを選択できないので困っています。
直し方がわかれば教えて下さい。

Comment: gradleのsyncは行いましたか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
できているはずです。

Answer (score 1):

文章を読む限り少し事象は異なるようにも思われますが、以下のリンク先に補完が効かなくなった場合の対処方法が書かれていました。
エラーがIDE上でのみ発生しているのであれば修復できる可能性はあります。
(逆に、Terminalからgraldewコマンドでビルド(`gradlew build`)した場合にも同じエラーが出るのであれば別の原因であると思われます。そのビルド時エラーを追記すると回答できる方が現れるかもしれません。)

[Android Studio - Auto complete and other features not working - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/)

対処策A.
File > Power Save Mode
にチェックが入っていれば外す。

対処策B.
File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...
メニューを選択し、 "Invalidate and Restart" を実行する。